# How can i automatically login with my demo user and password with a link?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I'm using .net core 2 with my project, i'v created a demo user with limited permissions.

i'm tring to create a link in the login page that automatically login with this demo user, it have a password.

How can i use or set that link/button to let the user login with demo user without typing the user name and password ?

Comment: Are you using "basic" authentication?

Comment: yes "basic" authentication, individual user account.

Comment: In that case, if you don't mind the password being visible, you should be able to create a link in the format: `https://username:password@yoururl.com`

Comment: This URL doesn't work, it requre username and password again.

Comment: any idea ??????